# Resize /dev/root partition

Tags: linux, partition, gentoo

I'm attempting to install Gentoo through VirtualBox. Well, technically I've already installed it, but I still need a WM. While trying to `emerge` Xorg , I ran out of space, and so I resized the /dev/sda3 (main) partition by deleting it and creating a new one, but unfortunately, the /dev/root partition(?) doesn't resize with it, and I can't modify it with fdisk (can't open/detect it). I've read it's a symlink, so I guess it's not technically a partition? I don't know. I'm using Systemd rather than OpenRC if that matters (probably doesn't but I felt like I should mention it).

With `df -h` I'm getting

```
Filesystem    Size  Used  Avail  Use%  Mounted on
/dev/root     3.7G  3.5       0  100%  /
```

(Can't post whole thing since I don't have mouse support installed)

Comment: The partition is just dumb storage, the filesystem is the bookkeeping that tells how things are stored in that storage. You need to update that bookkeeping too, that is, to resize the filesystem. If it's ext4, you're looking for `resize2fs`, if some other fs, then some other equivalent

Comment: See: [Difference between resize2fs and lvresize?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/535477/170373), [How do I resize partitions and filesystems on them?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169395/170373), [Why do I need to do resize2fs after lvextend?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/416886/170373)

Comment: Ah, thanks that worked!