# Shrink root LVM on LUKS2 btrfs root partition to enlarge swap partition

Tags: arch-linux, lvm, btrfs, luks

Here's my setup

```
$ lsblk
NAME                   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1                259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1            259:1    0   100M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2            259:2    0   250M  0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p3            259:3    0 238.1G  0 part
  └─Be-Water-My-Friend 254:0    0 238.1G  0 crypt
    ├─Arch-swap        254:1    0     2G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    └─Arch-root        254:2    0 236.1G  0 lvm   /
```

I have one main LUKS2-encrypted partition (`nvme0n1p3`), with one LVM volume group (`Be-Water-My-Friend`) containing two logical volumes `Arch-swap` and `Arch-root`.

The `Arch-root` is a **btrfs**.

When I set that up, I only chose 2GB of swap which turns out to be insufficient for my needs. I would like to increase that to 24GB of swap.

For that, I think I need to

1. boot on a USB live key
2. decrypt the LUKS2 partition
3. mount the `Arch-root` volume
4. shrink the `Arch-root` file system with

   ```
   btrfs filesystem resize -22g
   ```
5. remove the `Arch-swap` logical volume
6. recreate the `Arch-swap` logical volume taking all available space in the `Be-Water-My-Friend` volume group.

Is there anything I'm missing? I really don't want to screw that up!

Comment: Because it’s LVM, you don’t need to recreate the swap volume here. You can just resize it in place and then run `mkswap` with the correct UUID option to update things. The nonlinear nature of the resultant LV might be a (small) performance issue on rotational media, but it just won’t matter on an SSD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need one extra step between 4 and 5 -- shrink the `Arch-root` logical volume using `lvresize -L-22G Arch/root` (`lvresize` has option `--resizefs` to resize both the LV and the filesystem, but it currently doesn't support btrfs so you can't use it here). [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/535497/196468) nicely explains difference between resizing filesystem (btrfs in your case) and the block device (LVM logical volume).

You also might want to use `--uuid` with `mkswap` to set your old swap UUID for the new swap. Swaps are usually not referred with UUID in `/etc/fstab` and GRUB, but using the old UUID might save you some problems.

Also if you just want a bigger swap, you can create a [swap file on btrfs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/btrfs#Swap_file) and use it as second swap.

Comment: Oh waw did not know about swapfiles! Just created one now and this solved the issue immediately! I don't want to get into trouble trying to resizing everything so the swapfile solution works for me just fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

A small correction:

Step 2 should be: *unlock* the LUKS2 partition (with a `cryptsetup open --type luks ...` or equivalent command).

Step 2.5 should be added: verify the presence of the `Arch` volume group and ensure it's been activated, with e.g. `vgscan; vgchange -ay Arch`. (Depending on which live media you're using, the system may or may not auto-activate the VG as the encrypted partition is unlocked.)

Step 4.5 should be added: shrink the LV after you're sure the filesystem inside it has been successfully shrunk:

```
lvresize -L-22G Arch/root
```

---

Also, `Be-Water-My-Friend` is the name throuch which the encrypted device is accessed, and thus also the name of the LVM Physical Volume (`/dev/mapper/Be-Water-My-Friend`).

The name of the LVM volume group is simply `Arch`. In `lsblk` listing, the names of LVM Logical Volumes are presented in the form `VGname-LVname`, so e.g. `Arch-swap` means logical volume `swap` in volume group `Arch`.

If the VG/LV name includes hyphens (minus signs), those will be doubled to distinguish from the single hyphen that acts as a delimiter between the names of the VG and the LV.